# Error no encuentra librerías al generar .exe desde .jar java

Tags: java, jar, exe

Estoy acabando mi proyecto en java con Netbeans y quiero crear un ejecutable para que pueda ser usado en cualquier pc. El programa hace uso de una serie de librerias como Itext o Mysql. Mi procedimiento es darle al boton de "clean and build" en Netbeans, con esto me genera un .jar y ahora lo que hago es usar el programa **Launch4j** para cambiar mi .jar a un .exe. Sigo todos los pasos pero al acabar y cuando pruebo a ejecutar el .exe me da un error, pues dice que no encuentra la librerias, y no se como solucionarlo. Espero me puedan ayudar, gracias y un saludo.

Comment: En cuanto el .exe se ejecuta en otra localización que no es donde estan esas librerias, las rutas relativas se rompen y no las encuentra, es probable que tengas que llevarte esas librerias junto a tu .exe para que funcione. Para los ejecutables de programas desarrollados en .NET ocurre lo mismo.

Answer (score 0):

Si añades esto al final del archivo build.xml las librerias que uses deberían incluirse en el .jar de manera que al generar el .exe no necessites una ruta relativa para acceder a ellas:

```
<target name="-post-jar">
    <property name="store.jar.name" value="Nombre de tu app"/>
    <property name="store.dir" value="dist"/>
    <property name="store.jar" value="${store.dir}/${store.jar.name}.jar"/>

    <echo message="Packaging ${application.title} into a single JAR at ${store.jar}"/>

    <jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist" includes="*.jar"/>
        <zipgroupfileset dir="dist/lib" includes="*.jar"/>

        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main.class}"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>

    <zip destfile="${store.jar}">
        <zipfileset src="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"
        excludes="META-INF/*.SF, META-INF/*.DSA, META-INF/*.RSA"/>
    </zip>

    <delete file="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar"/>
    <delete dir="${store.dir}/lib"/>
    <delete file="${store.dir}/README.TXT"/>
</target>
```

Comment: Acabo de probarlo pero me da error nada mas compilarlo desde el Netbeans , diciendo que no encuentra las librerias, por otro lado si doy a la opcion "clean and build" me devuelve un error **lib does not exist** para la linea **<jar destfile="${store.dir}/temp_final.jar" filesetmanifest="skip">** .